# Is there in difference of assert implementation and std::abort()?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++

I'm trying to activate specific feature of llvm(clang) compiler called 'continuous mode', which would help me to get code coverage even though program was terminated.
With program which includes std::abort() code coverage is written great, but programs with false assert statements can't write their coverage in proper way. If there is a false statement in assert, it calls __assert_fail and it calls std::abort(), so I can't figure out, why there is a difference in code coverage with abort() and with assert. Maybe there is some important difference between std::abort() and assert->__assert_fail from point of clang++ compiler?
I'll really appreciate any help and thoughts about that!

Answer (score 1):

If `NDEBUG` is not defined, then `assert` writes, in an implementation defined way, output to `std::cerr`, then it calls `std::abort`. If `NDEBUG` is defined, then `assert` is a no-op.

`std::abort` terminates the process unless `SIGABRT` is being caught by a signal handler passed to `std::signal` and that handler does not return.

That's pretty much it really. With that in mind it should be possible to configure the code coverage tool as appropriate.

Comment: So, if NDEBUG is not defined, assert just calls std::abort() with writing an assert message to std::cerr?

Comment: @Andersen: Yes, that's broadly correct though `std::abort` is called after the implementation defined bit.